# How to add break line in <h:outputText /> value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm trying break line in `<h:outputText />` value.

I simply put a `<br>` in my value as HTML theory. But it doesn't work and a page error show up.

When I removed the `<br/>`. It works again properly.

My code is:

```
<h:outputText value="[#{order.product.code}] #{order.product.name} <br/> #{order.qty}"/>
```

I tried another way.

```
<h:outputText value="[#{order.product.code}] #{order.product.name} &#10 #{order.qty}"/>
```

No change at all.

Comment: I found that by simply setting the property **escape="false"** in the tag, and keeping the <br/> it works for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `&lt;` for `<` & `&gt;` for `>`, then make your html tag.

---

**Like:**

```
&lt;br /&gt; - For <br />
```

Then you have to tell the renderer not to escape html tag, place `escape= "false"` attribute inside `<h:outputText />`.

---

According to your requirement try this,

**Sample code:**

```
<h:outputText value="value-one &lt;br /&gt; value-two &lt;br /&gt; value-three" escape="false" />
```

**Output:**

```
value-one 
value-two 
value-three
```

Answer (score 6):

Why exactly do you need `<h:outputText>`? You don't seem to taking benefit of any of its additional features on top of plain EL in template text.

Just get rid of it and write it like so:

```
[#{order.product.code}] #{order.product.name} <br/> #{order.qty}
```

Note that this is not possible in legacy JSP, but given that you're using PrimeFaces, which doesn't have a JSP compatible tag library (JSP is deprecated >4 years ago), then you should surely be using Facelets.

Comment: Thank you very much.. @BalusC

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple `h:outputTex` tags with `< br />` tags inbetween. Try the following:

```
<h:outputText value="[#{order.product.code}]"/>
<br/>
<h:outputText value="#{order.product.name}"/>
<br/> 
<h:outputText value="#{order.qty}"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

Or use `escape="false"`:

```
<h:outputText value="[#{order.product.code}]&lt;br /&gt;#{order.product.name}&lt;br /&gt;#{order.qty}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: If user want to use inside `<p:panelGrid />` it may cause some miss alignment.. Have can it would help??

Comment: Wrap it in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

Comment: This is hard for developer to write 3 lines of code instead single line??

Comment: Good point regarding PrimeFaces <code><p:panelGrid></code> as each <code><h:outputText></code> will move to a new cell. See my updated answer, based on @Vasil-Lukach's answer. That should do what you want in one line.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use multiple outputText cuz it's inside <p:panelGrid>

Comment: yap, It only print <br/> instead of breaking line.

Comment: you should add `escape="false"` as a attribute.!! then only it will work.!!

Comment: @hurleytom Yep.!! your update answer looks similar to mine.!!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much everyone..!
Especially @Wanna coffee and @hurleytom.
Your codes really work.

```
<h:outputText value="[#{order.product.code}]&lt;br /&gt;#{order.product.name}&lt;br /&gt;#{order.qty}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: :) , When I tried your answer, I didn't see the escape="false". That's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Add attribute `escape="false"` in `h:outputText`. If your `value` contains `<br />` then you will have break line in text.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a possibility to do it in Java code, `<br />` should work there.